# What's the best way to store a number (<= 10k) of huge csv files (~200k lines) in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I tried to store them as a whole string in `text` column but there're errors when I was trying to save huge strings (over `45` millions chars). Are there any better options than to create `long row_index` column as a clustering key and store `.csv` line-by-line (each csv record will be a line in the table).

Write/read constraints: there's 1 write only (as soon as we create that `.csv` file), there's a small number (`<= 10`) reads for a specific file as well. And we'd probably like to optimize for fast writing, if possible.

Thanks.